# Force Macbook Pro to start as soon as power is connected

Tags: macbook-pro, power

It is incredibly frustrating to me that my Macbook Pro won't start for 15 minutes after the power is connected if the battery was completely drained.  It's obviously waiting until the battery is sufficiently charged so that it won't crash if the power is pulled, but I really don't care - I will deal with any consequences of this as long as I don't have to wait the 15 minutes.

Is there any way to force the Macbook to boot as soon as it has power?

Comment: What model is this? That's not my experience. Perhaps it's symptomatic of some other power supply problem. Have you reset the SMC?
Also: how often are you completely draining the battery? Perhaps Try not to?

Comment: It is a 2015 Macbook Pro 13".  This has happened on all Macbooks I've ever worked on.

The battery gets drained if I leave it even overnight without the power.  The battery itself is in good condition, and lasts hours when I use it, but something must be keeping it alive and draining it in the background.  This is another issue though.  Because of this, every time I start it, I need to wait until it gets to 5% charge before it will turn on.  I will try doing the SMC reset like you suggest.

Comment: I'd investigate what is draining the battery overnight. If the laptop is shut, it should use just a few % at most. If you fix that, then you won't need to wait for it to start every morning.